# How to pass parameter inside Angular.js query service the proper way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the folder name inside my query function.

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.people = getResult.query({api: 'person'});
```

And in my services, I have, so far:

```
.factory('getResult', function($resource) {

  var getResult = $resource('api/:path/:method/:id', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params: {path:'@api', method:'get'}, isArray:true },
      save: {method:'POST', params: {method:'save'} },
      get: {method:'GET', params: {method:'edit'} },
      remove: {method:'DELETE', params: {method:'remove'} }
    });

    return getResult;

});
```

The URL I'm getting is `http://localhost/project/api/get?api=person` but what I need is `http://localhost/coral/api/person/get`

I'm a newbie to Angular. What is the right way to do this, and why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getResult = $resource('api/:path/:method/:id',{path:'@api'}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params: {method:'get'}, isArray:true },
```